# $\chi$ varies over characters of $F$ of order dividing $m$, $\chi^{'}$ varies over characters of $F_s$ of order dividing $m$

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, characters, zeta-functions

A month ago I've asked two questions about rationality of the zeta function.  The pages that belongs to my question are [(linked here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011485/trying-to-understand-why-the-zeta-function-is-a-rational-function-under-certain) Unfortunately I'm still clueless, but some steps are clear now.

We start with:

$$ \sum_{\chi_0^{(s)},...,\chi_n^{(s)}} \chi_0^{(s)}(a_o^{-1}) \cdots \chi_n^{(s)}(a_n^{-1})g(\chi_0^{(s)}) \cdots g(\chi_n^{(s)}) \mbox{ } \mbox{ } \mbox{ }\mbox{ } \mbox{ }    $$

$\chi_i^{(s)}$ are multiplicative characters of $F_s$, such that  $\chi_i^{(s)m} = \varepsilon$, $\chi_i^{(s)} \neq \varepsilon$ und $\chi_0^{(s)} \cdots \chi_n^{(s)} = \varepsilon$ .

We showed that $\chi^{'} = \chi \circ N_{F_s/F}$ is a character of $F_s$ with:

**(a)** $ \chi \neq \rho $ implies that $\chi^{'} \neq \rho^{'} $

**(b)** $ \chi^{m} = \varepsilon $ implies that $\chi^{'m} = \varepsilon $

**(c)** $ \chi^{'}(a) = \chi(a)^s $ for all $a \in F$.

with the help of the information above I can **almost** replace  $$ \sum_{\chi_0^{(s)},...,\chi_n^{(s)}} \chi_0^{(s)}(a_o^{-1}) \cdots \chi_n^{(s)}(a_n^{-1})g(\chi_0^{(s)}) \cdots g(\chi_n^{(s)}) \mbox{ } \mbox{ } \mbox{ }\mbox{ } \mbox{ }    $$  with $$ \sum_{\chi_0,...,\chi_n} \chi_0(a_o^{-1})^s \cdots \chi_n(a_n^{-1})^sg(\chi_0^{'}) \cdots g(\chi_n^{'})$$ why **almost?** : I only need to show the part  " it follows that as $\chi$ varies over characters of $F$ of order dividing $m$, $\chi^{'}$ varies over characters of $F_s$ of order dividing $m$ ". Please help me here.

If you need more information. Please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure I got everything, but the statement *it follows that as χ varies over characters of F of order dividing m, χ′ varies over characters of F of order dividing m.* follows easily from the cyclicity of the character group.

Comment: Presumably $m$ is a factor of $q-1$, $F$ is the field with $q$ elements, and $F_s$ is the field with $q^s$ elements. Whenever $G$ is a cyclic group of order $\ell$, the same holds for its dual group $\hat G$. It follows that (assuming $m\mid\ell$) $G$ has exactly $m$ distinct characters $\chi\in\hat G$ with the property $\chi^m=\varepsilon$. In view of this, both $F^*$ and $F_s^*$ have exactly $m$ characters with that property. Because the norm map $N:F_s\to F$ is surjective, composing it with distinct characters of $F$ gives rise to distinct characters of $F_s$. Done.

Comment: I did see your earlier questions, but I was busy with other duties, and didn't have the time to look at the details. Sorry about that.

Comment: Of course you are supposed to start with $n=1$.. As I said in the first question everything is about the function $1_{x \in (F_{q^s})^m}$ which can be defined as a sum over the characters of $F_{q^s}$ whose order $|m$. Thus, if $m$ divides $q−1$, letting $r=\frac{q^s−1}{q−1}$, assuming $gcd(m,r)=1$, as a sum over the characters $\chi \circ N_{F_{q^s}/F_q}(a) = \chi(a^r)$ with $\chi$ in the characters of $F_q$ whose order $|m$. If $x \in F_q$ then $\chi(a^r) = \chi(a)^r$ by definition of characters.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki Lahtonen and reuns for your answers. (: